# PyAudio error : AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

i have installed Pyaudio in my pc (Windows 10) but It doesn't work in my project. There isn't pyaudio packet in my imports because when i try to install it, It appears a message where It says that the I failed the installation. In realty, i don't know if i need to import the package.

When i start the application I get this error:
"AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation"

I found topics in stackoverflow about this problem and I tried everything but I couldn't solve.
I tried:

1. to install it with these commands "pip install pyaudio" and "pip3 install pyaudio";
2. to install by "pipwin";
3. to install by "pyaudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl".

I am using python3.8 for my project;

Everytime It says that is installed (it's true) but I don't see in folder of the project. WHY?

The code where I use pyaudio:

```
def record():
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Talk: ")
    audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print('You said: {}'.format(text))
    except:
        print("I can't recognize your voice")
```

Comment: The `pyaudio` that you can install using `pip` usually does not contain Windows binaries. `pip` will try to compile from source but that often fails for several reasons, such as, you don't have the right compiler. You say you are using Python 3.8 and you installed `pyaudio` from `pyaudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`. As the `cp37` in the filename indicates, that is the Python *3.7* version of the wheel. Look for a wheel with `cp38` in the name from the same place you found the one that you used. And uninstall the old one before installing the new one.

Comment: I did what @BoarGules said me, but i get the same error: "AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation"

Comment: What happens when you enter `--pip version` at a command prompt?

Comment: @BoarGules give me this error "'--pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Sorry: `pip --version` not `--pip version`.

Comment: @BoarGules this is the answer: "pip 22.0.4 from c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)"

Comment: Okay. So your `pip` is for Python 3.8 and you used it to install `pyaudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` which is for Python 3.7. Is it not clear why that might be a problem?

Comment: I installed pyaudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38m‑win_amd64.whl but i get the same error

Comment: I solved it! I don't why but the project used the python 3.10. I have installed the pyaudio‑0.2.11‑cp310‑cp310m‑win_amd64.whl and I solved the issue